# Lost Sharepoint passphrase

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 server in one server, and the SQL database in another server.  I lost the passphrase and I can not recover it because if I try to reset it from the SPPowerShell it can connect to the SQL Server, and in the SQL server I have not install Sharepoint.

What can I Do?

Comment: Use a password management system in the future?

Answer (score 0):

`$passphrase = ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force` (type the **passphrase** you want to use).

`Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase -Confirm`